# Linux header files for Win32 typedefs like BOOL, LONG, and WCHAR

Tags: c, windows, linux, porting

I'd like to compile [this clone of xcopy](http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/trunk/reactos/base/applications/cmdutils/xcopy/) as a linux binary. I commented out all the win32 include files, and now it complains about things like WCHAR, and LONG. These are simple typedefs. Is there a header for linux that deals with these things? I know as soon as I solve this issue I'll discover that the win32 headers actually get used for things. Then I'll have to actually get down to the hard work of porting things. For now I'd like to get past this hurdle.

Comment: See: [Windows headers - Windows Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx). [wchar_t](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character) is compiler-specific, and on Win32 (which Visual C++ compiles to), it is assumed to be 16-bit.

Comment: The UTF8 and UTF16 is going to complicate your porting effort, because the two operating systems have different conventions. Good luck.

Comment: Since that code is from the ReactOS source, I would start looking there or at WINE's source for the headers.

Comment: see header in http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/trunk/reactos/include/psdk/windef.h?view=markup

Answer (score 0):

You might try compiling it with libwine as a step towards dropping the dependency entirely.

On Debian-based systems,

```
apt-get install libwine-dev
```